# Remove digits from number without reversing the number

Tags: c, reverse, digits

I got an exercise where I need to create a function that get two parameters, number (long) and digit (int) and I have to remove the digit from the number and return it.

When I do the exercise I reverse the number and in the end I reverse it again to get the original number.

I wanted to know if there is a way to do the exercise without reversing the number twice.

```
long myFunction(long number, int digit){

int tmp = 0;
if (digit <= 9 && digit >= 0){

    while (number != 0){  

        if (number % 10 != digit){

            tmp = (tmp + (number % 10)) * 10;

        }
        number = number / 10;
    }
    tmp = tmp / 10;

    int rev = 0, remainder;
    while (tmp != 0) { // Reverse an Integer

        remainder = tmp % 10;
        rev = rev * 10 + remainder;
        tmp /= 10;
    }
    return rev;

    }
    return number;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A different approach could be to track the position of the digit you want to add to the result (by multiplying it by 10<sup>position</sup>). This way, you won't have to reverse the number when you're done:

```
long removeDigit(long number, int digit) {
    long result = 0L;
    long multiplier = 1L;
    while (number > 0L) {
        int currDigit = (int) number % 10;
        if (currDigit != digit) {
            result += multiplier * currDigit;
            multiplier *= 10;
        }
        number /= 10;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Pure logic! OP: there are other ways that can be faster but involving or assuming fixed types and sizes: https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html

Comment: `(int) number % 10;` is incorrect.  Perform `%` first, not cast. IAC, cast has little need here.